# Replace all symbols in a matrix with their numbered forms

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a matrix made mostly from `"x"` with a few `0`'s thrown in:

```
list = {{0, "x", "x", 0}, {0, "x", "x", "x"}, {0, "x", "x", 
   "x"}, {"x", "x", "x", "x"}, {"x", "x", "x", "x"}, {"x", "x", "x", 
   "x"}, {"x", "x", "x", "x"}, {"x", "x", "x", "x"}, {0, "x", "x", 
   "x"}}
```

I know that there are 31 `"x"`'s in the matrix, and I want to replace each of them with a numbered variable: `x1`, `x2`, and so on til `x31` (without quotations). Here's the expected result:

```
(* {{0, x1, x2, 0}, {0, x3, x4, x5}, {0, x6, x7, x8}, {x9, x10, x11, 
  x12}, {x13, x14, x15, x16}, {x17, x18, x19, x20}, {x21, x22, x23, 
  x24}, {x25, x26, x27, x28}, {0, x29, x30, x31}} *)
```

Below is the list of the numbered variables that you may use:

```
numberedx = Table["x" <> ToString@i // Symbol, {i, Range@Count[list, "x", {2}]}]
(* {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, 
x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20, 
x21, x22, x23, x24, x25, x26, x27, x28, x29, x30, x31} *)
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. My gut tells me that some procedural method is in order since each `"x"` is replaced by its numbered form, then the next `"x"` down the line is replaced by the next member in the list of numbered variables. Unfortunately I'm very uncomfortable with procedural programming. I also tried `MapIndexed` but the `0`'s are mapped as well. I'd really appreciate any help or insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ReplaceAll` solution:

```
i = 1;
list /. "x" :> Symbol@StringJoin["x", ToString[i++]]
```

The same thing can be achieved with `Map`:

```
i = 1;
Map[If[# == "x", "x" <> ToString[i++] // Symbol, #] &, list, {2}]
```

They both give:

```
{{0, x1, x2, 0}, {0, x3, x4, x5}, {0, x6, x7, x8}, {x9, x10, x11, 
      x12}, {x13, x14, x15, x16}, {x17, x18, x19, x20}, {x21, x22, x23, 
      x24}, {x25, x26, x27, x28}, {0, x29, x30, x31}}
```

Answer (score 6):

Pickett's answer should get the job done but I encourage you to use [indexed objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html):

```
Module[{i = 0},
  list /. s_String :> x[++i]
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the replacement would not stop after the first `"x"` is replaced by `x1`. Does the `++` have anything to do with it?

Comment: @seismatica I don't know why you think only the first `"x"` would be replaced.  `/.` is `ReplaceAll`.  `++i` is used to increment a counter with each replacement that is made. (Or each replaced expression that evaluates, to be more correct.)  I am sorry if that is not helpful, but I don't understand your confusion so I find it hard to address.

Comment: For some reason I thought I have to use `//.` because sometimes `/.` might only replace the first instance. I guess that's the problem only for significant replacements that alters large interconnected parts of the expression, so it wouldn't be the problem here as only a single `x` is replaced.

Comment: @seismatica It is not really about "large interconnected parts" but: (1) simple precedence of rules and (2) direction of traversal.  By the first I mean something like this: `{1, 1, 1} /. {_Integer -> 1, 1 -> 2}` where `2` will never appear in the output because the first rule will match anything that the second will and it is applied first.  `//.` will not change that.  By the second I mean e.g. `{1, 2, 3} //. {x_Integer :> x + 1, x_List :> Mod[x, 2]}`.  Here the entire expression is tested and found to match the second rule; the first rule is not *also* applied to the replaced expression.

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
Module[{i = 0, l = #, f}, 
   f[x_String] := Symbol[x <> ToString[++i]];
   f[x_] := x;
   Map[f, l, {2}]] &@list
```

> ```
> {{0, x1, x2, 0}, {0, x3, x4, x5}, {0, x6, x7, x8}, {x9, x10, x11, x12},
>  {x13, x14, x15, x16}, {x17, x18, x19, x20}, {x21, x22, x23, x24},
>  {x25, x26, x27, x28}, {0, x29, x30, x31}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a solution using `Position` and a `Table` of `Set`'s i.e. "set x at this position to the numbered variable with the same index `i`". I really appreciate all of your answers, and hopefully I will get used to using `++i` in the future.

```
Clear[replacex]
replacex[l_List] := Module[{lCopy = l, positionx, numberedx},
  positionx = Position[l, "x"]; 
  numberedx = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, Range[Count[l, "x", {2}]]}]; 
  Table[lCopy[[Sequence @@ positionx[[i]]]] = numberedx[[i]], {i, Length[numberedx]}];
  lCopy]

replacex[list]
(* {{0, x1, x2, 0}, {0, x3, x4, x5}, {0, x6, x7, x8}, {x9, x10, x11, 
  x12}, {x13, x14, x15, x16}, {x17, x18, x19, x20}, {x21, x22, x23, 
  x24}, {x25, x26, x27, x28}, {0, x29, x30, x31}} *)
```

---

I also found that these work to replace the second to last line in my module:

```
Function[i, lCopy[[Sequence @@ positionx[[i]]]] = numberedx[[i]]] /@ Range@Length[numberedx];
Set[lCopy[[Sequence @@ positionx[[#]]]], numberedx[[#]]] & /@ Range@Length[numberedx];
```

but not this

```
(lCopy[[Sequence @@ positionx[[#]]]] = numberedx[[#]] &) /@ Range@Length[numberedx];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `ReplacePart`:

```
pos = Position[list, "x"];

idx = ToString /@ Range[Length@pos];

numbdx = Symbol@*StringJoin @@@ Thread[{Array["x" &, Length@#], #}] &@idx;

ReplacePart[list, Thread[pos -> numbdx]]

(*{{0, x1, x2, 0}, {0, x3, x4, x5}, {0, x6, x7, x8}, {x9, x10, x11, x12}, 
   {x13, x14, x15, x16}, {x17, x18, x19, x20}, {x21, x22, x23, x24}, 
   {x25, x26, x27, x28}, {0, x29, x30, x31}}*)
```